# Unable to connect my postgres database using Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am using Docker but it does not work. I don't understand why...

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` :

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  database:
    image: "postgres" # use latest official postgres version
    env_file:
      - database.env # configure postgres
    volumes:
      - database-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/ # persist data even if container shuts down
volumes:
  database-data: # named volumes can be managed easier using docker-compose
```

Here is my database.env :

```
# database.env
POSTGRES_USER=admin
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass
POSTGRES_DB=db
```

I typed that and I got that:

```
$ docker-compose up
2021-01-15 19:57:11.683 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

So it is good.

Then that:

```
docker-compose run database bash
```

I tried that, but I got that:

```sh
$ su - postgres
$ psql --host=localhost --username=admin --dbname=db
psql: error: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Whereas if I type in my terminal linux that:

```sh
$ sudo su - 
$ su - postgres
$ psql --host=localhost --username=admin --dbname=db
```

I have to enter the password and it works...

Why ist that and what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`docker-compose run` launches a new container.  Within that container, `localhost` is that container, not the other database container that's already running.  As described in [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/), you can use the existing database container's service name from the `docker-compose.yml` file as a host name; so one way to connect to the database is

```sh
sudo \                         # launching containers can require root permission
docker-compose run database \  # start a new container
psql \                         # with psql as the main command
  --host=database \            # connecting to the existing database container
  --username=admin \
  --dbname=db
```

Assuming you've published `ports:` from your container

```yaml
services:
  database:
    image: postgres
    ports:         # These two lines are very routine;
      - 5432:5432  # do you already have them?
```

then you can also connect to the database using the host's IP address and the first `ports:` number.  This is indistinguishable from running the database server directly on the host.  Since you make a TCP connection to connect to the database, you don't need to be any particular user to do it.

```sh
# without needing sudo at all
psql \                # launch the client directly on the host
  --host=localhost \  # connecting to a database on the same machine
  --username=admin \
  --dbname=db
# --port=5432         # needs to match first ports: number; this is the default
```

(You might be thinking of `docker-compose exec`, which is a debugging tool that can get a shell or otherwise run a command against a running container.  You shouldn't normally need that to interact with a database, though; you just need an ordinary client library or command-line tool like `psql`.)

Comment: Thank you but when I type that `sudo \                         # launching containers can require root permission
docker-compose run database \  # start a new container
psql \                         # with psql as the main command
  --host=database \            # connecting to the existing database container
  --username=admin \
  --dbname=db` I got the same error : `Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
`

Comment: That implies it's not seeing the `--host=database` option.  Try removing all the newlines and comments and retyping it, `sudo docker-compose run database psql ...`